# Bad string error in JSON

Tags: json, json.net

I'm a beginner in JSON. I'm getting the bad string error for following when trying to test this JSON on www.jsoneditoronline.org.

```
{
astrMethodName:
"BL2X2/g7NkZk0PR5YODRDSmsGpk
vXf9xEXiGHYwk2co=",
astrParameters: "",
astrDataValueField:
"1zzftXOCj6fFUf9IYSCzhw==",
astrDataTextFiel
```

Can you please help

Comment: I take it the linebreak in the middle of the `astrMethodName` is how it appears in the editor? Javascript string literals can't span lines.

Comment: It appears like below{
astrMethodName: "BL2X2/g7NkZk0PR5YODRDSmsGpkvXf9xEXiGHYwk2co=",
astrParameters: "sdfvdf",
astrDataValueField:"1zzftXOCj6fFUf9IYSCzhw==",
astrDataTextFiel:"gsdgfg"
}

Answer (score 1):

it should be formatted like so:  (note the quotes I added)

```
{
  "astrMethodName": "BL2X2/g7NkZk0PR5YODRDSmsGpkvXf9xEXiGHYwk2co=",
  "astrParameters": "sdfvdf",
  "astrDataValueField": "1zzftXOCj6fFUf9IYSCzhw==",
  "astrDataTextFiel": "gsdgfg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` is not valid because it is not formatted properly.

**Reason for invalid JSON**

[image]

**Valid `JSON` should be like this**

[image]